# Save Expression on Encrypted attribute in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-dynamodb

I'm using save expression on an encrypted attribute named `transactionAmount` while updating data in dynamo DB. However the update query is failing with ConditionalCheckFailedException. The data is encrypted on client side during initial persistence in dynamodb in way same as described [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/client-side-encryption-for-amazon-dynamodb/). Following is the code:

Data Transfer Object:

```
public final class SampleDTO {

@DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = CommonDynamoDBSchemaConstants.UNIQUE_KEY)
@Getter(onMethod = @__({ @DoNotTouch }))
private String uniqueKey;

@DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = CommonDynamoDBSchemaConstants.EVENT_RUNNING_TIME_EPOCH)
@Getter(onMethod = @__({ @DoNotTouch }))
private Long eventRunningTimeInEpoch;

@DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = CommonDynamoDBSchemaConstants.INSTRUMENT_TYPE)
@DynamoDBTypeConverted(converter = InstrumentTypeConverter.class)
@Getter(onMethod = @__({ @DoNotTouch }))
private InstrumentType instrumentType;

@DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = CommonDynamoDBSchemaConstants.TRANSACTION_AMOUNT)
private String transactionAmount;

}
```

Data Access Code:

```
// fetches data from dynamoDB based on unique key passed to it.
SampleDTO sampleDTO = getSampleDTO("testLedgerUniqueKey");
sampleDTO.setInstrumentType(InstrumentType.MACHINE);

DynamoDBSaveExpression saveExpression = new DynamoDBSaveExpression();
            Map<String, ExpectedAttributeValue> expressionAttributeValues =
                    new HashMap<String, ExpectedAttributeValue>();

        expressionAttributeValues.put(
                CommonDynamoDBSchemaConstants.LEDGER_UNIQUE_KEY,
                new ExpectedAttributeValue(true)
                        .withValue(new AttributeValue(sampleDTO.getLedgerUniqueKey())));
        expressionAttributeValues.put(
                CommonDynamoDBSchemaConstants.TRANSACTION_AMOUNT,
                new ExpectedAttributeValue(true).withValue(
                        new AttributeValue(sampleDTO.getTransactionAmount())));

        saveExpression.setExpected(expressionAttributeValues);
        saveExpression.setConditionalOperator(ConditionalOperator.AND);

        dynamoDBMapper.save(sampleDTO, saveExpression, null /*dynamoDBMapperConfig*/);
```

Answer (score 0):

**ConditionalCheckFailedException:**

You are trying to update a record that does not exist with your query condition. Please verify your query condition to make sure your query returns a record.

**Reference:**

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Programming.Errors.html#Programming.Errors.MessagesAndCodes

> You specified a condition that evaluated to false. For example, you
>   might have tried to perform a conditional update on an item, but the
>   actual value of the attribute did not match the expected value in the
>   condition.

Hope it helps.

Comment: the record does exists in dynamoDB. If I remove the expressionAttributeValue on `transactionAmount`, the conditional save is successful. The only problem is `transactionAmount` being present as encrypted value. AFAIK, dynamoDBMapper handles encryption/decryption for us.